# a command executed when pattern rule is not true in awk, what's wrong?

Tags: bash, awk

A strange awk phenomenon again.. (this happens all the time :) )
I have a file aaa below.

```
[first]
aaa
bbb
[second]
ccc
ddd
eee
[third]
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
```

I'm trying to print the line numbers of each section which starts with a header embraced in bracket. So I wrote a simple awk script CntSecLines.awk below(it's being debugged, so with some prints).

```
 /\[/{print "header found : "; print $keep " : " cnt; keep=$1; cnt=0}
!/\[/{print "header not found"; cnt = cnt+1; print "keep = " $keep;}
```

Below is the exection result for aaa.

```
ckim@stph45:~/test] awk -f CntSecLines.awk aaa
header found : 
[first] : 
header not found
keep = aaa
header not found
keep = bbb
header found : 
[second] : 2
header not found
keep = ccc
header not found
keep = ddd
header not found
keep = eee
header found : 
[third] : 3
header not found
keep = fff
header not found
keep = ggg
header not found
keep = hhh
header not found
keep = iii
```

I intended it to be updated only when there is the section header. But why is the variable 'keep' updated every line? when I print the variable $keep, we can see it's being updated every non-section-header line.

Comment: What do you mean? `keep` is printed only for non-header lines, which seems obvious with the code you have because it is part of the non-header line match condition

Comment: `$keep` is the field with the number that is stored in the variable `keep`, not the value of the variable itself (e.g., `keep = 1; print $keep` will print field 1, i.e., `$1`). Hence when you print `$keep`, the thing that is printed also depends on the line you are on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `awk`, not `bash`. In `awk` you don't use `$` to get variable value (well, with exceptions, like for positional arguments `$1`, `$2`...).

```
awk '
   /\[/{print "header found : "; print keep " : " cnt; keep=$1; cnt=0}
   !/\[/{print "header not found"; cnt = cnt+1; print "keep = " keep;}
' <<EOF
[first]
aaa
bbb
[second]
ccc
ddd
eee
[third]
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
EOF
```

will output:

```
header found : 
 : 
header not found
keep = [first]
header not found
keep = [first]
header found : 
[first] : 2
header not found
keep = [second]
header not found
keep = [second]
header not found
keep = [second]
header found : 
[second] : 3
header not found
keep = [third]
header not found
keep = [third]
header not found
keep = [third]
header not found
keep = [third]
```

Tested on [repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/TechnicalMixedVaporware).

I believe `awk` interprets `$keep` as, like, `$` with a string `[blabla]`, like `$"[blabla]"`, then `"[blabla]"` is converted from a string to a number, which results in `0`, so `$keep` is interpreted as `$0`, which prints the whole line.

Comment: Hi, I see. I almost always make a mistake when using awk occasionally. Thanks for the debugging and analysis!

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted your requirement as "count the lines in each bracket-delimited section."

```
$ awk '/^\[.*\]$/ {c=0; print; next} {print ++c, $0}' file
[first]
1 aaa
2 bbb
[second]
1 ccc
2 ddd
3 eee
[third]
1 fff
2 ggg
3 hhh
4 iii
```

- `/^\[.*\]$/` - If the record begins with a literal `[` and ends with a literal `]`
- `{c=0; print; next}` - Set/reset count, print record, skip remaining rules
- `{print ++c, $0}` For records not matching the first rule, print a pre-incremented count, the Output Field Separator `,` and the record `$0`.